# Update and delete in oracle using java

Tags: java, oracle11g, sql-update

I have a table named bcfsite with a field named activestate.

```
update bcfsite set activestate = 1 where bscname like '%B361Z%'
```

When I run the above query SQLPlus or Oracle SQL Developer, it works fine without any problems, but when I run it in Java using this code:

```
String sqlstrString = "update bcfsite 
                       set activestate = 0 where bscname like '%B361Z%' ";
PreparedStatement ps = d.prepareStatement(sqlstrString);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeUpdate();
```

or this code :

```
ResultSet rs = DBConnection.RunStatement(sqlstrString, d);
```

My program pends and doesn't pass the update statement.

I changed the table and column and tried delete instead of update but still I see the same problem.

Comment: Add a `;` at the end of your java `sqlstrString`

Comment: Does your database `Connection` have autocommit set to `true`?

Comment: No stacktrace? It just hangs (pends?)?

Comment: when i add ; at the end of sqlstrString i got this exception
ORA-00911: invalid character

Comment: @StijnGeukens yes i checked.there is no problem with my connection.

Comment: Are you using the same user / pass to log into Oracle via Java as you are from your SQL Plus and SQL Developer?  If not, it may be permissions.

Comment: A possible issue: if you table bcfsite is very big, it'll spend some time doing the update, especially since you are using a `'%...'` in your `where` clause. No magic about that. Try to do an `explain plan` with sql*plus and post the execution plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am putting this is the answer box because there is not enough room in the comments...

```
String qString = "update bcfsite set activestate = 0 where bscname like ?";
```

That is the correct way to do this with a replaceable parameter.  Remember when using the like operator everything passed to it is a varchar2 as far as oracle is concerned so:

```
ps.setString(1,"%B361Z%");
```

Again, this is the correct way to accomplish this.

The resulting string passed to oracle via jdbc will look like:

```
update bcfsite set activestate = 0 where bscname like '%B361Z%'
```

setString() applies the correct markup so the oracle query parser will see a correct query.

Queries with a "?" in them are not simply string replaced.  The statement is parsed by the server, and then the parameter(s) are passed to the server.

BTW this was answered in several places on SO.  Please learn how to search SO and it will shorten your response time considerably and not waste our time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
String sqlstrString = "update bcfsite " +
                       "set activestate = 0 where bscname like '?'";
PreparedStatement ps = d.prepareStatement(sqlstrString);
ps.setString(1, "%"+"B361Z"+"%");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeUpdate();
```

And a second approach would be:

```
 ...set activestate=0 where bscname like CONCAT('%', ?, '%')"; 
 ...
 ps.setString(1, "B361Z");
```

Comment: i try this but there is no diffrent.

Comment: Give it one more try with single quotes around the question mark.

Comment: thank you @Costis Aivalis i try your upadate approach but still the program  doesnt pass the update statement :(

Comment: no when i add semi colon at the end of sqlstrString i got ORA-00911

Comment: @Coastis yes you are right. but the point is that when i use no semicolon the the program doesnt pass the update statement.

Comment: A shot in the dark... I modified the sqlString in line 1.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following approach first to clear out it updates atleast one row through Java code, don't give wild characters try to update single row.

```
String sqlstrString = "update bcfsite 
                       set activestate = 0 where bscname=?";
PreparedStatement ps = d.prepareStatement(sqlstrString);
ps.setString(1, "B361Z");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeUpdate();
```

This may rule out other issues like connectivity/different schema ..

Please post the result.

Comment: i try it and without wild character to update just one row but still the program doesnt pass the update statement.

Comment: is the problem with DML operations with this table or all tables in the schema? are you able to do select on this table through the code?

Comment: yes i can select and insert but i got problem with delete and update

Comment: let check this way.. how much time it takes to update single row through SQLplus.. can you post doing that - put set timing on and run update statement

Comment: Also if you can post no of rows in the table you are updating

Comment: i check the time with sqlplus.the result is:
313ms elapsed and its for one row.